# Basis of a field in a subfield

Tags: linear-algebra

Let K be a field and F be a subfield of it. Is it true that there always exists a basis of K contained in F?

Edit: I meant a basis of K over F.

Comment: Do you mean that K is a field extension of F?

Comment: A basis of what? A basis aof $K$ as $F$ vector space? In that case the basis cannot be all in $F$ if $F$ is a proper subfield ...

Comment: Yes, K is regarded as a vector space. What if it has an infinite basis?

Comment: If $F\subset K$, any basis will be a subset of $K$, not $F$. Maybe you meant a basis for $K$ over $F$. It’s a fairly deep theorem that *any* vector space $V$ over the field $F$ has a basis, even if the basis is infinite. There’s nothing special about the vector space $K$, even though it’s also a field in its own right.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what's the difference between a basis of K contained in F and a basis for K over F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saying "$K$ is a vector space" isn't clear. You need to specify what field you're talking about, especially if you're talking about two fields.

> Does $K$ have a basis as an $F$-vector space which is contained in $F$?

No. The $F$ span of a subset of $F$ will be trapped in $F$, and can't generate $K$ if $K$ is bigger than $F$.

> Does $K$ have a basis as an $K$-vector space which is contained in $F$?

Yes. $\{1\}$ is a basis, and actually $\{\alpha\}$ is a basis for any nonzero $\alpha\in F$.

> Does $K$ have a basis as an $F$-vector space?

Yes, since all $F$ vector spaces have (many) bases, no matter if they are finite or not.

> Could you explain what's the difference between a basis of K contained in F and a basis for K over F?

"Over $F$" means that the coefficients used on the basis elements are from $F$, but the basis elements themselves do not have to be from $F$. "contained in $F$" implies the basis elements are in $F$.